# Open generated HTML report in post-build event

Tags: visual-studio, post-build-event, opencover, reportgenerator

In the post-build event of my unit test project I run OpenCover and ReportGenerator to get a code coverage report:

```
del "$(SolutionDir)TestResults\Coverage\*.*"

"$(SolutionDir)packages\OpenCover.4.5.1923\OpenCover.Console.exe" 
-register:user 
-target:"$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
   Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" 
-targetdir:"$(ProjectDir)bin\$(ConfigurationName)" 
-targetargs:"/testcontainer:\"$(TargetPath)\"" 
-output:"$(SolutionDir)TestResults\Coverage\coverage.xml" 
-filter:"+[MyProject]* "

$(SolutionDir)packages\ReportGenerator.1.9.1.0\ReportGenerator.exe" 
-reports:"$(SolutionDir)TestResults\Coverage\coverage.xml" 
-targetdir:"$(SolutionDir)TestResults\Coverage"

call "$(SolutionDir)TestResults\Coverage\index.htm"
```

The final step is to open the generated HTML report. With the current `call` command it opens the HTML report in my default web browser. But I would like it if the report could get opened within Visual Studio itself.

If and how would I achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you hope to achieve by the report opening up in Visual Studio rather than in the browser?

Comment: It's for convenience really. When I'm building my project and it completes it will display the build result and coverage report in the same window, rather than switching between VS and the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have actually got it to work using PowerShell and the `Navigate` method in the VS core automation wrapper, [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/envdte.itemoperations.navigate%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
I replaced the last `call` command with the following:

```
powershell 
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted 
-Command "& { $dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::
                     GetActiveObject(\"VisualStudio.DTE.11.0\"); 
              $dte.ItemOperations.Navigate(
                     \"$(SolutionDir)TestResults\Coverage\index.htm\"); }"
```

And that opens the report in a new browser tab inside the VS project.

Comment: As an FYI for people trying this with Visual Studio Express (Web Developer), replace `VisualStudio.DTE.11.0` with `VWDExpress.DTE.11.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple thing worked for me in post build event-

```
start http://localhost/MYWeb/Home.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use devenv to open the file using the [command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) switches.

```
devenv /edit $(SolutionDir)TestResults\Coverage\index.htm
```

but it may open it up as a file to edit rather than to view.

Comment: Your last comment is correct, it does open the file in edit mode, rather than browse mode.

Comment: That gives the edit mode, not viewing mode. Plus if you run devenv inside post build event you get `exited with code 9009` message.